# Elements starting by center of a stackpanel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How can I insert elements into a stackpanel, and they start positioned by center?
Something like this:

|_ _ x _ _ |

|_ x x _ _ |

|_ x x x _ |

The "x" are the elements, and the "_" are blank space.

Is there something already implemented?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could wrap your elements in a `Grid`:

```
<Grid Width="720">
  <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto" >
    <!-- elements go here -->
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This is the simplest approach in my opinion. 
You also need to make sure that the StackPanel's Width="Auto" and Grid's Width="720"(some fixed value as needed).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the elements in an element that has `HorizontalAlignment` set to `Stretch`, e.g.:

```
<StackPanel>
  <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TextBlock Text="something short" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
  </Border>
  <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TextBlock Text="something a bit longer" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
  </Border>
  <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TextBlock Text="something more than a bit longer" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
  </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<StackPanel>
  <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <!-- element x -->
  </StackPanel>
  <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <!-- element x -->
    <!-- element x -->
  </StackPanel>
  <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <!-- element x -->
    <!-- element x -->
    <!-- element x -->
  </StackPanel>
<StackPanel>
```

This produces the example you gave.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on the elements you are adding to the StackPanel, but in general look for the following: make sure that each element has the HorizontalAlignment set to Stretch (so they span the entire width) and then set the HorizontalContentAlignment to Center.